# How to reload datatable keeping the page and filtering searching if exist without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I'm using dataTable plugin to show data from Database , The table looks like:

```
name   location     actions
jack   New York   Edit , Delete
john   London     Edit , Delete
...    ...        Edit , Delete
```

The Adding/Editing/Deleting functions are working well , But I have to refresh the page to see the results.

How to reload the table but keep the previous parameters like page and searching if they exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
table.ajax.reload(null, false);
```

The second parameter is resetPaging, if is true will reset the datatable to default, if is false will hold the current paging position. The first parameter is a callback function.

For more information, see: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Answer (score 0):

If using and XHR data source with DataTables:

```
// Init DataTables with XHR source
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  ajax: "my/xhr/data/source"
});

// Reload the table every 30 seconds 
setInterval( function () {
  table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000);
```

Of course, you could reload under a refresh button on after you add/edit/delete rows in your XHR callbacks.